# UIView set frame weirdness

Tags: iphone, ipad, uikit

I have the following code:

```
    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame  chapterNum:(int)newChapterNumber pageNum:(int)newPageNumber
    {
NSLog (@"Frame:x:%f y:%f width:%f height:%f",frame.origin.x,
                                             frame.origin.y,
                                             frame.size.width,
                                             frame.size.height);
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    NSLog (@"View Frame:x:%f y:%f width:%f height:%f",self.frame.origin.x,
           self.frame.origin.y,
           self.frame.size.width,
           self.frame.size.height);
    ......
    }
```

Im running on the simulator (in landscape mode) when I look at the results of the console logs i see:

2011-06-17 09:17:16.428 MyApp[16454:207] Frame:x:0.000000 y:0.000000 width:128.000000 height:96.000000

2011-06-17 09:17:16.433 MyApp[16454:207] View Frame:x:-64.000000 y:-48.000000 width:128.000000 height:96.000000

Why is the origin of the View frame not the same as the frame im using , is it noteworthy that the value are exactly half of the size variables (plus a - sign).  Any help is greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

First (and has nothing to do with the problem, just a style issue) use NSStringFromCGRect instead of printing it out yourself.

```
NSLog(@"frame = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(frame));
....
if(...) {
    NSLog(@"self.frame = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
}
```

What view is your superclass? Is it a generic UIView or one of your making? Is there nothing in your `initWithFrame:` method before the ....?

The significance of half your width and height becoming the new origin is that your view has had it's `center` moved to 0,0. Not sure why it would be doing that, thus the question about your superclass.

For more info see the docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) and look at the docs for the `center` property.

Comment: thanks bill NSStringFromCGRect, is a good score for me ! My view is subclassed from UIView. I've read the docs and still have no idea why my center would being shifted but that does in fact seem to be happening ...